# How to I assign my Combo Box's SelectedIndex to Array coordinates?

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have an array:

```
decimal[,] SmoothieListDecimal = { {5.99M, 6.99M, 7.99M, 8.99M},
                                   {6.99M, 7.99M, 8.99M, 9.99M} }
```

And I have two combo boxes:

cmbSize and cmbStyle

cmbSize has: Small, Medium, Large, and King, which make up the values in the array.

The second combo box is cmbStyle, which includes only two selections, "Regular" and "Organic". The "Organic" prices are $1.00 more expensive and derived from the second row.

So, for example, if a user selects a "Medium" size and "Regular" style, the price would be pulled from row 1, column 1 in the array.

My question is, how do I set my variables to their respective array coordinates, and furthermore, how would I code the equation to handle this price selection? 
I am using (Visual Studio 2015 and C#)
Thanks!

Comment: You're not assigning the `SelectedIndex` to anything.  You get an element of an array by index; by two indexes in your case. Do you know how to do that?  If not, do some research and learn.  Now you simply provide the two `SelectedIndex` properties of the `ComboBoxes` where those indexes are expected.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a class containing informations about smoothie prices:

```
public class SmoothiePrices
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, double> SizeAndPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Fill this with your info:

```
private List<SmoothiePrices> prices = new List<SmoothiePrices>();

public void InitSmoothies
{
   prices.Add(new SmoothiePrices() 
   {
     Name = "Regular",
     SizeAndPrice = new Dictionary<string, double>() 
     {
        {"Small", 5.99},
        {"Normal", 6.99}
        // And so on
     };
   });
}
```

Now you have created a data structure and can fill the combos:

```
private void InitStyleCombo()
{
  this.cmbStyle.DisplayMember = "Description";
  this.cmbStyle.DataSource = this.prices;
}
```

The last thing to do is to fill the cmbSize depending on the selection of the cmbStyle combo.

```
private void cmbStyle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var smoothiePrice = this.cmbStyle.SelectedValue as SmoothiePrice;
   this.cmbSize.DisplayMember = "Key";
   this.cmbSize.ValueMember = "Value";
   this.cmbSize.DataSource = smoothiePrice.SizeAndPrice;
}
```

To access the selected price for the size use:

```
var selectedPrice = (double)this.cmbSize.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but one easy way (but certainly not the best or most robust) is to load the `ComboBox.Items` in the correct order for `SmoothieListDecimal`.

```
decimal price;
int column = cmbSize.SelectedIndex; // 0=Small,1=Medium,2=Large,3=King
int row = cmbStyle.SelectedIndex;   // 0=Regular,1=Organic

if (column < 0)
    MessageBox("Please select a size");
else if (row < 0)
    MessageBox("Please select a style");
else
    price = SmoothieListDecimal[row, col];
```